# Is it possible to add @Secured or @PreAuthorized annotations on an entire class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

It seems logical to secure an entire class of controllers rather than each method. Can I do this:

```
@Controller
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
public class accountPages {
   //Controllers
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

from Spring Security 3 - PACKT Publishing

> Be aware that the method-level security
>   annotations can also be applied at the
>   class level as well! Method-level
>   annotations, if supplied, will always
>   override annotations specified at the
>   class level

Comment: From my testing, that is not true anymore.  If you have a class level and method level security annotation (either @Secured or @PreAuthorized), they both get run.  If the method level annotation is more restrictive, this is just fine.  If it is less restrictive, then it doesn't work.  I ended up splitting my less restrictive methods out into another controller.